# WPF DataGrid TemplateColumn not switching between edit and normal templates

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid and I am trying to display a TextBlock when not in edit mode and a ComboBox when editing. I would think this would be easy, but it is not. I can only get it to working using a brute force method of placing the controls in a Grid and using a Visibility binding to show the controls in turn; which is a real pain.

Why does the following not work:
I can get one or the other to show, but not both based on cell editing.

```
<DataGrid Background="DarkGray" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" CanUserAddRows="false" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        SelectionChanged="DataGrid_SelectionChanged" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}"
        behaviors:DataGridBehavior.OnSelectAction="{Binding Path=OnSelectionChanged}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Button" Binding="{Binding Button}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Button Display" Binding="{Binding ButtonDisplay}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Reason Code" Binding="{Binding ReasonCode}" />
    <!--<DataGridTextColumn Header="Count Stamps" Binding="{Binding CountStamps}" />-->
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Count Stamps">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox IsEditable="True" SelectedValue="{Binding CountStamps}"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Value" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CountStamps}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}" Width="*" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Your CellEditingTemplate and your normal CellTemplate are looking fine. This would work (i.e., showing the combobox edit mode is engaged for a cell in the "Count Stamps" column). That it is not working in your case is probably some side effect of some other things happening in your code (like, some code-behind stuff triggered by some binding, behavior, or some other event, perhaps...)

Comment: Thank you very much. The Selection_Changed event handler was interfering. This was added to enter edit mode using a single click on a cell. What was throwing me off was the SelectedIndex on the combo box.